# post for rest service using restTemplate with object

Tags: json, spring, date, jackson, resttemplate

suppose I have a model like this:

    `public class Foo {
    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date date;
    }`

and the controller is like this:

    `@RequestMapping("/getFoo")
    public @ResponseBoddy Foo getFoo(Foo ff) {
    return new ff();
    }`

in the client side I have done something like this:

    `Foo request = new Foo();
    RestTeplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    rest.postForObject("http://hostAddress:8080/Fooo/getFoo", request, String.class);`

and my client Foo is the same as the service Foo
but something is going wrong, the content type is invalid..
my question is: is it possible to post for object using a java bean ? and how to it, and if there is guidelines where to start building and consuming web services I'll be thankfull

Answer (score 0):

Since you return the Foo object in the controller, you should wirte the RestTemplate in this way:

```
RestTeplate rest = new RestTemplate();
rest.postForObject("http://hostAddress:8080/Fooo/getFoo", request, Foo.class);
```

Otherwise you can write:

```
@RequestMapping("/getFoo")
public @ResponseBoddy Foo getFoo(Foo ff) {
Foo ff = new Foo();
String result = null;
//Convert ff in String and valorize result
return result;
}
```

Hope this helps

Angelo

Comment: I think you can always return a String, even when the return type is not a string, however when returning an Object I get it null;

Comment: Also add `@RequestBody` to your controller, so `getFoo(@RequestBody Foo ff)`. Here's a little more context on the error. You are posting a `String`, which uses the [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) which results in a Content-type of `text/plain`. Posting the object as `Foo.class` as Angelo suggested will cause the  `Jackson2HttpMessageConverter` to be used to convert to JSON, which will post with `application/json`. Hope that helps.